# SQL: How to select ONLY orders that occur every three weeks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an orders table where orders are placed every Thursday. Accordingly, each order has `fiscal_week_number` between 1 and 52 associated with it.

Each order is grouped in batches, where one order can contain multiple transactions, each billed on a separate week. For example, `order_number` 0001 billed on `fiscal_week_numbers` 4, 5, 6, 7 and had `transaction_numbers` 100000001, 100000002, 100000003, 100000004. Assume the transaction_numbers are non-sequential and random.

Some of the orders bill every week, some bill every two weeks, some bill every 3 weeks, etc. How can I query the table to only show orders that bill every X weeks?

For example, I would like to find out how many orders (that is, distinct `order_ids`) bill every 6 weeks but I can't figure out the SQL.

For example, say I wanted to grab only orders that occur every three weeks from the following data set. I would expect to receive only order `00003`. It doesn't really matter if all the order data is there or just the id.

```
|00003   |319229           |20            |
|00003   |319230           |23            |
|00003   |238678           |26            |
|00003   |319231           |29            |
|00003   |190659           |32            |
```

```
+--------+-----------------+--------------+
|order_id|transactionnumber|fiscal_week_no|
+--------+-----------------+--------------+
|00001   |278100           |1             |
|00001   |278101           |2             |
|00001   |278102           |3             |
|00001   |278103           |4             |
|00001   |278104           |5             |
|00002   |319224           |10            |
|00002   |319225           |12            |
|00002   |319226           |14            |
|00002   |319227           |16            |
|00002   |319228           |18            |
|00003   |319229           |20            |
|00003   |319230           |23            |
|00003   |238678           |26            |
|00003   |319231           |29            |
|00003   |190659           |32            |
|00004   |319232           |26            |
|00004   |190660           |30            |
|00004   |190661           |34            |
|00004   |190662           |38            |
|00004   |319233           |42            |
|00005   |190663           |40            |
|00005   |319234           |45            |
|00005   |190664           |50            |
|00005   |190665           |3             |
|00005   |190666           |8             |
|00006   |319235           |10            |
|00006   |190667           |16            |
|00006   |190668           |22            |
|00006   |319236           |28            |
|00006   |190669           |34            |
|00007   |319237           |20            |
|00007   |190670           |28            |
|00007   |190671           |36            |
|00007   |319238           |44            |
|00007   |190672           |52            |
|00007   |190673           |8             |
+--------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Your data and your explanation do not match, which makes it harder to understand what you  really want. Please show us the result that you want for your sample data.

Comment: @GMB added some more explanation.

Comment: Is there ever a fiscal week 53? (52 * 7 = 364 leading to an extra week every few years. And leap days also affect the mix.) Can there be data for more than one year?

Comment: @HABO yes, there is data for more than one year and to my surprise there many orders where the fiscal week is 53.

Comment: Since you have data for more than one year, but don't have the year for each row, you can't handle year crossings. Weeks `52` and `1` might be 1, 2, 51 (where `1` came first), 53 or 54 weeks apart. If there are multiple values _that you assume are in the same year_ you can guess what the pattern might be. As the number of years increases eventually you'll have `1` through `53` for an order and can make it mean anything. (See [Mark Twain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics).) If `transaction_number` always increases it helps a little, but ... .

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, orders bill every three weeks if the `fiscal_week_no` column is always the same, modulo 3.  So, one method is:

```
select order_id
from t
group by order_id
having min(fiscal_week_no % 3) = max(fiscal_week_no % 3);
```

Note that this does not guarantee that they are billed *every* three weeks (we could add an additional check for that.  But these would be the orders on the same billing cycle.

Comment: This is a really elegant solution... How would you go about adding that check for consecutive bill cycles?

Comment: An order that ships in fiscal weeks `52` and `3` fails: `52 % 3 = 1`, `3 % 3 = 0`. Since `52` isn't a multiple of `3` year crossings are a problem. (Waiting for the OP to confirm that multiple years of data may exist. Or a week 53 now and then.)

Comment: @qotsa42 . . . For consecutive bill cycles, I would just use `count(*) = max(fiscal_week_no) - min(fiscal_week_no)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code could be useful too.  This will return the order_id's for whichever  number of transactions is set in the @bill_freq variable.  I used made up data.

```
declare @bill_freq          int=2;

;with rn_cte(order_id, transactionnumber, fiscal_week_no, wk_rn) as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by order_id order by order_id, fiscal_week_no) wk_rn
    from (values ('00001', 278100, 1),
                 ('00001', 278101, 2),
                 ('00002', 278102, 3),
                 ('00002', 278103, 4),
                 ('00003', 278104, 5),
                 ('00004', 278105, 7),
                 ('00004', 278106, 9)) v(order_id, transactionnumber, fiscal_week_no))
select order_id
from rn_cte
group by order_id
having max(wk_rn)=@bill_freq;
```

Results

```
order_id
00001
00002
00004
```